# Automating Deployment of SOA project onto weblogic server using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins, soa, weblogic12c

I need help to deploy OSB composites onto Weblogic server using Jenkins. I am using maven as my build tool. Right now I am deploying the project using mvn pre-integration-test command. I need help to write deployment script/plugin to deploy my artifacts onto weblogic server.

This my osbProject POM.xml that uses service bus plugin to generate sbar and I am using DEV profile to deploy the generated sbar onto weblogic 12c

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
   <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus</groupId>
    <artifactId>sbar-project-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>ServiceBusApplication1</groupId>
<artifactId>SBProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>sbar</packaging>

<description/>
 <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>oracle-servicebus-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
                    <configuration>
                    </configuration>    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
  </build>

<profiles>  
   <profile>
        <id>Dev</id>
       <properties>
            <oracleServerUrl>http://serverDev.com:7001</oracleServerUrl>
            <oracleUsername>username</oracleUsername>
            <oraclePassword>password</oraclePassword>
            <oracleHome>path to oracle home</oracleHome>
            <customization>path to configuration file</customization>
        </properties>

   </profile>
 </profiles>
</project>

This deploy onto sbconsole of  SOADEV server
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`distibutionManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html)

> Distribution information for a project that enables deployment of the
>   site and artifacts to remote web servers and repositories respectively

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>internal.repo/</id>
    <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
    <url>Host to Company Repository/ Server in your case</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

***Note*** - Do replace the details according to the server you want to specify to upload/deploy the artifacts to.

Using which you can later simply execute the maven command

```
mvn deploy
```

to deploy your artifacts to the server url which would also include the current `pre-integration-test` that you are executing as well.

Comment: I am not deploying to any staging area. We dont have nexus/artifatory to stage our artifacts. I need to deploy thoes artifacts onto my different environments like QA,INT,UAT and prod.

Comment: I am using Profiles to define those environments. But I need to help to separate my build configuration from deploy configuration.

Comment: @Joe those environments has some host IP or name?

Comment: @Joe for use of profiles you can better update the question with complete details.

Comment: I have updated question with POM.xml for your reference.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Currently I am working on automation OSB Deployments and have any idea how to deal with it...